# Why did the timeline revert back to its original state after Janeway destroyed the temporal core in the episode "Year of hell"?

Tags: star-trek, time-travel, star-trek-voyager

Voyager "Year of Hell part 2":

> TUVOK [OC]: Captain, we won't be protected.
>
> JANEWAY: Exactly. **If that ship is destroyed all of history might be
>   restored**. And this is one year I'd like to forget. Time's up.
>
> (Voyager ploughs into its mortal enemy with a big KaBOOM!)

Why did the timeline revert back to when Voyager first entered the episode? Why were all the changes the ship made undone? Wouldn't things have just remained how they were at that moment?

Comment: I have no source, so I'll only comment - I think they just got lucky. The core and the time weapon basicly misfired. It erased itself from existance. Luckily sparing Voyager. So they got double lucky. IMHO Voyager is the series where the heroes get lucky the most.

Comment: The real reason is that the writers feared change. They noticed that Year of Hell was by far the best (two-part) episode and ran the risk of making Voyager a good show, rather than an average show with occasional interest. So they had to back-pedal fast :D

Comment: Hi. I note you haven't accepted any answers for this question yet. If my answer addresses the question, would you please consider answering it for future viewers? If not, please let me know where I can improve it!

Answer (score 12):

The [Memory Alpha page on the 'Year of Hell' timelines](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Year_of_Hell) explains this as a result of the temporal core suffering damage thereby causing a temporal incursion:

> **The impact, and the resultant destabilization of the temporal core,
>   caused a temporal incursion within the weapon ship, *erasing all of its
>   previous changes***. As a result, Voyager was warned away from Krenim
>   space on Day 1 by the same ship they originally encountered (with much
>   less belligerency), and were able to plot a course around the Imperium

This is also supported by the description of events described in the specific [wiki page for that episode.](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Year_of_Hell,_Part_II_%28episode%29)

Now, what is a temporal incursion I hear you ask?  Well, [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Temporal_incursion) explains it as basically being an act designed to alter a timeline.  The basic answer to your question is then that by destroying the temporal core, it didn't just have an effect *immediately*, but had an effect *throughout time*.  Therefore, it basically *wiped its own existence from the timeline, meaning none of the changes from the Krenim ship occurred,* restoring the timeline to what it was originally.  The timeline, from the viewer's perspective, was restored to Day 1 of the year of hell, but really it just was the corrected timeline prior to the Krenim ship's activities.  That is, the timeline was reverted back to before the Krenim temporal core was created, not to day 1 of the 'year of hell'; we just saw the timeline from that point on and proceeded as though the Krenim ship hadn't made any changes.

Comment: +1 - it created (or restored) a timeline where the Krenim were no longer a large, aggressive empire.

Comment: Umm...I understand the what but I don't understand the why. You basically restated what happened. I'm trying to understand why it happened. The explanation you give in your paragraph doesn't make sense to me. Shouldn't time have been wherever it was at the point when the ship was destroyed? It was destroyed after 52% restoration and after a year of hell, so shouldn't it now be a year later and 52% of the Krenim empire restored? Why would there be a reset? Can you explain further?

Comment: @JMFB you need to think fourth-dimmensionally!  If I destroy a temporal core, not only does it impact us *now*, but it impacts the *past* as well - essentially it means it never existed, so the timeline is put back to the way it was originally i.e. from our perspective these events never occurred, but the timeline is what it would have been without the Krenim ship - doe that help?

Comment: @N_Soong no you just repeated the same thing again. The past is a relative thing. Unless you actually went back to the time when the Temporal ship first started making its changes and destroyed it at that point in time, the changes should stand. I'm not sure what you mean by 4 dimensional thinking, either it's a reference to vectoring in Euclidian  space or it's simply adding time to space(lxwxh). I'm not sure how that applies here.

Comment: @JMFB it's a BTTF reference ;)

Comment: @JMFB anyway, the idea that is presented in the show is that because you destroy the temporal core, it erases all the modifications that have been done to the timeline by that temporal core, as though nothing had ever changed.  That's why they return to that particular time - because the timeline was restored.  The timeline could have returned to any point, and it does in a way return to all points in history from that point of deviance where the core was first created.  The out of universe reason is that they probably just wanted to show that the year of hell hadn't happened to our heroes

Comment: @N_Soong: "They" don't "return" anywhere; we just see the restored timeline, starting from Voyager's first contact with the Krenim, as that happens to be the earliest moment in the restored timeline relevant for Voyager.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Apologies - slip of the tongue (so to speak)!

Comment: @JMFB the weapon removes an object from ALL of time, if you fire it at a planet all life on that planet NEVER existed (it not just dead today its whole history never happened. The time ship fired on itself -erasing its whole existence from all of time (past and present). Annorax even says this at the end of the episode "ANNORAX: The core is destabilising. It's going to cause a temporal incursion ***within*** the ship." - The weapon is designed to delete an objects ENTIRE past, it backfired and erased its own past because of the collision rather than just going bang in the present

Comment: Just to clarify the weapon doesn't time travel but the beam it fires **does***, the beam travels into the past destroying the object in the past, the beam fired at the ship, like a laser bouncing off a mirror - destroying itself in the past (erasing itself from all of time)